Eliminar atributo "selected" en lista opciones select
Estoy intentando eliminar el atributo "selected" de la lista de opciones de un select pero no funciona. Si en cambio agrego el attributo con setAttribute si que va.
¿ Como tengo que hacer para eliminar este atributo ?
Ejemplo para agregar atributo en primer elemento de la lista:
document.getElementById("idSelect").options[0].setAttribute('selected','selected')

Pero si lo quiero eliminar no puedo poner "removeAttribute" porque no me funciona:
document.getElementById("idSelect").options[0].removeAttribute('selected')

Aqui pongo un ejemplo mas extenso del codigo que tengo, en principio quiero eliminar cualquier 'selected' que haya en los elementos del select:
document.getElementById("idSelect").options.forEach( function (e) { e.removeAttribute('selected'); });


Debería funcionarte, verifica que tengas bien el id del elemento y el elemento exista, sino proporciona parte del html del select

Pégale un vistazo a esto, a ver si te sirve: https://jsfiddle.net/utb081mg/  La próxima vez pon un [example] que podamos ver el contexto, pues funcionar funciona, aunque quizás no como te crees.

@masterguru, me parece que el problema es justamente porque el elemento es el primero (posición 0). Al ser la primer opción no existe forma de que se visualice otra si no existe otra seleccionada.

@Marcos con Edge me funciona pero con Chrome no !! He ahí el problema

@Popularfan, es raro, a mi el ejemplo de masterguru me funciona en ambos navegadores.

@Marcos es verdad ahora el ejemplo funciona en Chrome. Voy a ver si hay algo mas en el código

También funciona en Firefox. Como tu código es JS, procura mostrar un [repro] como snippet.

@padaleiana voy a poner mas codigo

En javascript existen muchos tipos de objetos predefinidos y cada tipo cuenta con sus propias funciones. Y es así como un Array cuenta con la función forEach, pero los otros objetos ni siquiera los otros que son también colecciones deben tener por obligación la función forEach y es ese el error de tu código
Porque select.options es del tipo HTMLOptionsCollection el cual NO cuenta con una función forEach, por lo que no puedes utilizar dicha función.
Esto también pasa con selectores, por ejemplo:

getElementsByTagName retorna una HTMLCollection
querySelectorAll retorna NodeList (Este tipo de colección si tiene una función forEach)

En tu caso, puedes convertir select.options en un Array:
Array.from(document.getElementById("idSelect").options).forEach(e => e.removeAttribute('selected'));

Otra solución sería utilizar querySelectorAll que si tiene forEach
document.getElementById("idSelect").querySelectorAll("option").forEach(e => e.removeAttribute('selected'));

O también:
document.querySelectorAll("#idSelect > option").forEach(e => e.removeAttribute('selected'));

En resumen: Hay que tener cuidado con el tipo de datos que retornan los HTML

Otra opción es usar spread. Ejemplo [...document.getElementById("idSelect").options].forEach. PD: En este caso .options es opcional, pero por las dudas...

El problema es que tenia un forEach para eliminar el "selected" y no funcionaba bien:
document.getElementById("idSelect").options.forEach( function (e) { e.removeAttribute('selected'); }); // Esto me daba error

Luego con la ayuda del código de @masterguru he visto que con un for() me funcionaba bien:
let options = document.getElementById("idSelect").getElementsByTagName('option');
for (var i = options.length; i--;) {
   document.getElementById("idSelect").options[i].removeAttribute('selected');
}

Para hacerlo con un forEach() debia escribirlo asi:
 let options = document.getElementById("idSelect").getElementsByTagName('option');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, e => { e.removeAttribute('selected') });

